# getting messages from discord to append to list with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get messages from discord and putting the messages into a list named strlst but so far it's not putting the message into the strlst and no error in terminal. Since I'm using both @bot.event and @bot.command(), I have put a process command thingy (idk what that is). Here it is:

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    await bot.process_commands(ctx)

    if ctx.content == ".add ":
        ctx = ctx.content.lower()
        newctx = ctx[4:]
        strlist.append(newctx)

strlist = ["!cb","hello","no thank you", "you pass the butter"]

@bot.command(name="bb")
async def bb(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"WHAT DO YOU WANT ?")

    # This will make sure that the response will only 
be registered if the following
    # conditions are met:
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and 
msg.channel == ctx.channel and \
        msg.content.lower() in strlist

    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    if msg.content == '!cb':
        await ctx.send("GOING DOWN . . .")
    else:
        await ctx.send("OK , COOL STORY . . .")
        



    @bot.command(name="lst", help = "List of responses it will reply to", brief = f"The current responses available are:\n {strlist}\nNOTE:!cb cancels the bot")
    async def current_lst(msg):
        await msg.send("To add to the list, simply type .add [your message]")
```

This is the part that works:

User: !bb

Bot : WHAT DO YOU WANT ?

User: you pass the butter

Bot : OK , COOL STORY . . .

User: !bb

Bot : WHAT DO YOU WANT ?

User: !cb

Bot : GOING DOWN . . .

I want the part for .add to work like this:

User: .add I have a cool story        (and the bot adds this to strlst)

User: !bb

Bot : WHAT DO YOU WANT ?

User: I have a cool story

Bot : COOL STORY BRO . . .

Main point: I want to add user's message to the list. It would be appreciated if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean `if ctx.content == ".add ":` only checks whether the message exactly equals ".add". Use `ctx.content.startswith('.add')`. You can also use `print` or the debugger to identify the values in your program and where the problem might be.

And as for readability, you shouldn't do `ctx = ctx.content.lower()` since that overwrites a message object with a string, which will only lead to confusion down the linea

Comment: ive tried this and it still doesnt add the messages after .add to the list, but with using print i think i somehow know what to do know, thanks!